# Ubuntu server (version 19) not detecting ethernet cable

Tags: networking, server, 19.04, ethernet

So I want to connect my ubuntu server to ethernet but it isn't detecting it since when I try to ping google or ubuntu.com it giver error.

[ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIXTM.jpg)

[interface config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHq8s.jpg)

Comment: Try another Ethernet cable; they do break. If another cable does not help, check the other end; what is it plugged in to? Which socket number? Do other Ethernet devices on that same router work OK? Is it turned on?  Please click [edit] and tell us the make and model number of the router and the computer; make sure to get the model # from the same sticker as the serial #. Once you have that, click [edit] here and add that essential info to your question. Do not use Add Comment because it loses all formatting, so use [Edit] instead.

Comment: Do you notice that you have a DNS problem? You also have no IP. Have you tried statically setting the interface and then pinging an ip like 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @stratus Should I set up DNS is the interface file or in the router?

Comment: Well I wouldn't bother setting up the DNS until you statically set the IP/Gateway and try pinging 8.8.8.8. If that doesn't work, then like @K7AAY suggests try another cable. If it does work then either the router is not providing dhcp or the ubuntu server is having a problem configuring its interface (or its not set to take dhcp on that interface)

Comment: Its working now.

Comment: DeadSec did you unplug/replug the cable immediately before it started working, change Ethernet cables, or do something else immediately before it started working? Please advise.

Comment: I reinstalled the operating system with the ethernet cable connected and it set up everything on installation. I reinstalled for another reason but it happened to work.